# A function $d:M\times M \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defines a metric under certain conditions

Tags: metric-spaces

Let us consider the function on the set $M$

$$d:M\times M \rightarrow \mathbb R.$$

I want to show that it defines a metric space on $M$ if the following two conditions are hold:

1. $d(x,y) =0 \iff x=y$
2. $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$

So we need to prove that $d(x,y)\geq 0$ and $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ but I don't know how to prove these two things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us start by proving that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. You know that $d(x,y)\leqslant d(x,x)+d(y,x)$, but, since $d(x,x)=0$, this means that $d(x,y)\leqslant d(y,x)$. By the same argument, $d(y,x)\leqslant d(x,y)$.

Now, suppose that, for some $x$ and some $y$ in $M$, $d(x,y)<0$. Then $$0=d(x,x)\leqslant d(x,y)+d(x,y)<0.$$

Comment: Thank you :) I actually thought that in the task there are some facts missing.

Comment: Is supposing that d(x,y)< 0 in the second part of the solution necessary? Could we not just say for arbitrary $x \neq y$ that $$0=d(x,x) \leq d(x,y)+d(x,y) \Rightarrow 0 \leq 
 2d(x,y) \Rightarrow 0 \leq d(x,y) $$ ?

Comment: @Sofia Yes. That will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Choose $z=x$ in 2) to learn that $d(x,y) \leq d(y,x)$ using 1). 
Then replacing the roles of $x$ and $y$ yields $d(y,x) \leq d(x,y)$.
Altogether, $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

After that, choose $y=x$ in 2) to learn that $0 \leq d(x,z)+d(x,z)=2d(x,z)$. Hence $d(x,z)\geq 0$.