# Metric spaces with two conditions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

If $X$ is an non-empty set and $d: X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ has the following properties

$d(x,y)=0$ if and only if $x=y$

$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+\color{red}{d(z,y)}$

Prove that d defines a metric on X.

I need to prove that
$d(x,y) \geq 0$

$d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

I know [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2550280/a-function-dm-times-m-rightarrow-mathbb-r-defines-a-metric-under-certain-co) result.

But the conditions that are set are different, I have tried to do it in an analogous way, but I think that with the conditions that are given it does not meet that it is a metric.

The question falls on the fact that in the statement that I mention you have to d(x,y) $\leq d(x,z)+\color{red}{d(y,z)}$
I would appreciate any hint or if you can help me prove that it is not metric.

Comment: $X$ should be a non empty set for a metric to be defined ;)

Comment: If $X$ is truly empty then isn't everything true vacuously?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake

Comment: Of course, I have marked it in red, what happens is that if here I take $z =y$ I have that $d(x, y) \leq d(x, y)$

Comment: Pointing it out here because it wasn't clear to me either first. The question linked had the term $d({\color{red} y}, {\color{blue} z})$ while this question has $d({\color{blue} z}, {\color{red} y})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $X = \{1, 2\}$ and $d$ defined as
$$d(1, 1) = d(2, 2) = 0; \; d(1, 2) = 1; \; d(2, 1) = 2.$$

This clearly satisfies the first condition.
The second condition is trivially satisfied in the following cases:

1. $z = x,$
2. $z = y,$
3. $x = y$.

Therefore, the only case to be checked is when the three are distinct. However, that clearly cannot happen.

Thus, we conclude that the given conditions do not ensure a metric.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: In general, this answer shows that a [quasi-metric](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Quasi-metric) need not be a metric.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @SahibaArora: interesting, I'll also point out that I think OP's requirements don't imply that $d$ is a quasi-metric since this $d$ will satisfy OP's conditions even if I change the $1$ to a $-1$.

Comment: an apology, I have a doubt, in the counterexample you give, what you do is show that it does not meet the second given condition? that is, i.e $d(x,y) \nleq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$

Comment: Or what do you mean that the second condition is satisfied with each of the 3 cases it presents?

Comment: The counterexample I give DOES satisfy the second condition of yours. However, it does not satisfy the conditions to be a metric since it does not satisfy symmetry. We have $d(1, 2)\neq d(2, 1)$.

Comment: To the proposer: If $z=x$  then $d(x,y)\le d(x,x)+d(x,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y). $ If $z=y$ then $d(x,y)\le d(x,y)+d(y,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y).$ If $z\ne x$ and $z\ne y$ then $x=y$ (otherwise  $x,y,z$ would be $3$ distinct members of $X$) and $d(x,y)=d(x,x)=0\le d(x,z)+d(z,y).$

Comment: but this would not serve also to exemplify that the example of the link is not a metric?

Comment: If you're referring to the quasi-metric link, then yes. I have shown that quasi-metric need not be a metric in general. (And also that the two conditions you gave does not ensure a metric.)